# jQuery Mobile Link Transitions When "data-ajax" Is False

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, transition

I am building a mobile website with jQuery Mobile and am setting up a link to a separate page with a pretty heavy AJAX call. As near as I can tell, because jQuery's Mobile's default link behavior (discussed here: [jQuery Mobile Docs - Linking Pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)) makes every link into an AJAX request, it is interfering with the AJAX call being made on `$(document).ready` on the page being linked to. By adding the attribute `data-ajax="false"` to my anchor tag linking to that page, this AJAX error disappears and the new page loads and operates normally.

But those transitions jQuery Mobile offers, esp. "fade," are running on every other page transition and, apart from sitewide consistency, look pretty slick. I'd like to be able to have this transition when I go to this page that now has `data-ajax="false"` in its link's attribute, but that appears to cancel out the transition effect -- if I add an additional attribute like `data-transition="fade"` in the anchor tag, that, perhaps understandably, won't work since I also have that `data-ajax="false"`attribute. I've also tried to add something like:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "fade";
    });
```

to the linking page, without success.

Am I hosed? Is there any other way I otherwise can't discover that forces the clicked link to run a jQM transition? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Transitions only work if you pull the new page into the current DOM and then slide/fade/whatever. This only works with Ajax. If you do regular links you drop the current DOM and load a new one - hence no transition possible.

Comment: Fair enough -- I'd hoped there might be a workaround.